# Definitions of irreducible three manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am trying to understand the definition of irreducible $3$-manifold. Let $M$ be a connected $3$-manifold.

> *Definition 1:* We say $M$ is irreducible if given any smoothly embedded submanifold $S$ of $M$ with $S\cong \Bbb S^2$, there exists a
> **smoothly embedded submanifold** $B$ of $M$ such that $B\cong \Bbb B^3$
> and $\partial B=S$.

Here, $\cong$ stands for being homeomorphic, $\Bbb S^2:=\{x\in \Bbb R^3:||x||=1\}$, and $\Bbb B^3:=\{x\in \Bbb R^3:||x||\leq1\}$. Note that for $\dim\leq 3$, the notion of being homeomorphic and being diffeomorphic are the same.

> *Definition 2:* We say $M$ is irreducible if given any smoothly embedded submanifold $S$ of $M$ with $S\cong \Bbb S^2$, there exists a
> **subset** $B$ of $M$ such that $B\cong \Bbb B^3$ and $\partial B=S$.

See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_manifold#Irreducible_manifold

Now, note that if $M$ is irreducible in the sense of Definition 1 (for example $\Bbb R^3$), then it's irreducible in the sense of Definition 2. What about other direction?

> Question: Let $M$ be irreducible in the sense of Definition 2. Is it
> then irreducible in the sense of Definition 1? In other words,
> Suppose we are given a three-manifold $M$ and a smoothly embedded
> submanifold $S$ of $M$ such that the following hold: $(1)$ $S$ is
> homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^2$, $(2)$ There is a subspace $B$ of $M$ so that
> $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb B^3$ with $\partial B=S$. Is $B$ a
> smoothly embedded submanifold $M$?

I guess that these two definitions are equivalent, because if I have a subset $B$ with $B\cong \Bbb B^3$ and $\partial B=S$, then taking smooth tubular neighborhood of $S$ in $M$, one can give a smooth structure so that $B$ is a smoothly embedded submanifold of $M$.

Comment: What does $B\cong \Bbb B^3$ mean?

Comment: Well if $\cong$ means a diffeomorphism, the author probably meant to assume $B$ is an embedded smooth submanifold. If $\cong$ means homeomorphism, then presumably $B$ is an embedded topological manifold.

Comment: Yes but the symbol $\cong$ doesn't mean anything for sets, so presumably it means $B$ with the subset topology, in which case it is an embedded subspace.

Comment: I'm trying to say that you can't describe a homeomorphism between a *set* and a topological *space*. So the hypothesis only makes sense if $B$ is an embedded subspace. That doesn't answer your question, but it's a starting point.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand; thanks for your comment. I have written it in the Question section, but I will not change subset to subspace as Wikipedia says subset, not subspace. Probably they are trying to mean subset with inherited subspace topology.